# Why --link-dest stops creating hardlinks when --relative is added?

Tags: rsync

Why is the first rsync command working perfectly creating a clone of /tmp/data to /tmp/bak **using hardlinks** but the second creates a clone by **copying bytes** instead of hardlinking?

```
rsync -a    --link-dest=/tmp/data  /tmp/data/  /tmp/bak/ # HARDLINKS
rsync -a -R --link-dest=/tmp/data  /tmp/data/  /tmp/bak/ # REGULAR COPIES
```

---

**Steps to test/reproduce**

```
cd /tmp/
rm -rf data bak                                                                                                                     
mkdir data bak 
echo foo > data/foo 
stat /tmp/data/foo | grep Inode
rsync -a    --link-dest=/tmp/data  /tmp/data/  /tmp/bak/
stat /tmp/bak/foo  | grep Inode                        
### Note that the inode is the same as above.

rm bak/*                       
rsync -a -R --link-dest=/tmp/data  /tmp/data/   /tmp/bak/
stat /tmp/bak/tmp/data/foo | grep Inode      
### Note that the inode is different.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the `-R` (`--relative`) flag, all paths become prefixed with the source path, including any `--link-dest` path.

Working this through with your example,

> ```
> rsync -a -R --link-dest=/tmp/data /tmp/data/ /tmp/bak/
> ```

what this means is that the link-dest path becomes `/tmp/data/tmp/data`. (You can see this more clearly with `cp -al /tmp/data /tmp/link` and using `strace -f rsync ... --link-dest=/tmp/link`.)

The solution in this instance is to use `--link-dest=/` so that the generated starting point becomes your desired `--link-dest=/tmp/data`

```
rsync -a -R --link-dest=/ /tmp/data/ /tmp/bak/
stat /tmp/bak/tmp/data/foo | grep Inode    # Same inode as source, with Links: 2
```

Comment: Good one. you can also add that :
In case you work with `rsync -a -R /tmp/./data/ /tmp/bak/` then the option should be until the `.` is: `--link-dest=/tmp`.

Comment: Thanks for the good explanation @roaima. It's a pity that `rsync -vvvvvv` has no hints at all about what is happening.

Comment: I only caught it when I changed the `--link-dest` source from `/tmp/data` to `/tmp/link` (as briefly described in the question), and ran `strace -f rsync ...` looking for `(f)stat` or `open` calls involving that alternate path.

Answer (score 0):

That's an interesting question.

When you use `rsync -R`, it will copy the `tmp/data` into the destination directory.

The thing is, that when rsync will copy, it will first check if the file exists in the directory given by the `--link-dest`:

Meaning, it will compare `/tmp/bak/*` with `/tmp/data/*`.

The problem is that, when you launch `rsync -R` command, the `foo` file will not be in a place that can be compared with /tmp/data/ to do the link, it will be in `/tmp/bak/tmp/data/foo`, while rsync, stupidely, would only do hardlink for it if it is a the root of the directories given (in that example, `/tmp/data` and `/tmp/bak`).